# PHP : Combine days with same start and end time

Tags: php, arrays

I have a timing for seven days. I want to print this timing, but want to show the same start and end time for combined days.

For example, if Monday until Friday have same timing, I should get this result :

```
Mon-Fri 9:00 to 17:00
```

If there's no start or and end time, I should get this result :

```
Sat-Sun Off Day.
```

This is my data :

```
Array ( 
    [0] =>
        Array (
            [customer_id] => 4
            [start_time] => 01:00
            [end_time] => 16:00
            [break_start] => 05:00
            [break_end] => 10:00
            [off_days] =>
            [time_interval] =>
            [day] => saturday
            [closed] =>
            [break] => 
        ) 
    [1] =>
        Array (
            [customer_id] => 4
            [start_time] => 04:00
            [end_time] => 17:00
            [break_start] => 09:00
            [break_end] => 10:00
            [off_days] =>
            [time_interval] =>
            [day] => sunday
            [closed] =>
            [break] =>
        )
    [2] =>
        Array (
            [customer_id] => 4
            [start_time] => 15:00
            [end_time] => 21:00
            [break_start] => 17:00
            [break_end] => 18:00
            [off_days] =>
            [time_interval] =>
            [day] => monday
            [closed] =>
            [break] =>
        ) 
    [3] =>
        Array (
            [customer_id] => 4
            [start_time] => 00:00
            [end_time] =>
            [break_start] => 00:00
            [break_end] => 00:00
            [off_days] =>
            [time_interval] =>
            [day] => tuesday
            [closed] => 1
            [break] =>
        )
    [4] =>
        Array (
            [customer_id] => 4
            [start_time] => 00:00
            [end_time] =>
            [break_start] => 00:00
            [break_end] => 00:00
            [off_days] =>
            [time_interval] =>
            [day] => wednesday
            [closed] => 1
            [break] =>
        ) 
    [5] =>
        Array (
            [customer_id] => 4
            [start_time] => 00:00
            [end_time] =>
            [break_start] => 00:00
            [break_end] => 00:00
            [off_days] =>
            [time_interval] =>
            [day] => thursday
            [closed] => 1
            [break] =>
        ) 
    [6] =>
        Array (
            [customer_id] => 4
            [start_time] => 00:00
            [end_time] =>
            [break_start] => 00:00
            [break_end] => 00:00
            [off_days] =>
            [time_interval] =>
            [day] => friday
            [closed] => 1
            [break] =>
        )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function renderDays($list){
    $times=array();
    foreach($list as $key=>$item){
        @$times[$item["day"]]["start_time"]=$item["start_time"];
        @$times[$item["day"]]["end_time"]=$item["end_time"];
    }

    $time_days=array("mon","tue","wed","thu","fri","sat","sun");
    $time_simple=array();
    $group_days=array();


    $time_index=0;
    for ($i=0; $i<6; $i++) {

        if ($times[$time_days[$i]]==$times[$time_days[$i+1]]) {
            array_push($group_days,$i+1);
            if (!in_array($i,$group_days)) {
                array_push($group_days,$i);
            }
            sort($group_days);
        } else {

            if (count($group_days)>1) {
                $group_name=$time_days[$group_days[0]]."-".$time_days[$group_days[count($group_days)-1]];
                $time_simple[$group_name]=$times[$time_days[$group_days[0]]];
            }


            //dont repeat if this week day already is in a group
            if (!in_array($times[$time_days[$i]],$time_simple )) {
                $time_simple[$time_days[$i]]=$times[$time_days[$i]];
            }

            $group_days=array();
            //reset the group

        }
    }

    //last verification if any group is left
    if (count($group_days)>1) {
        $group_name=$time_days[$group_days[0]]."-".$time_days[$group_days[count($group_days)-1]];
        $time_simple[$group_name]=$times[$time_days[$group_days[0]]];
    }
return  $time_simple; 
}
```

Then you use:

```
 $output=renderDays($list);

        //render final result as html
        foreach($output as $days=>$values){
            if (!empty($values["start_time"]) && !empty($values["end_time"])) {
                echo $days." ".$values["start_time"]." to ".$values["end_time"];
            } else {
                echo $days." Off Day";
            }
            echo "\n";
        }
```

For the $list  i used this testing array:

```
$h=array("day"=>"mon","start_time" => "01:01", "end_time" => "16:00");
$h2=array("day"=>"tue","start_time" => "01:00", "end_time" => "16:00");
$h3=array("day"=>"wed","start_time" => "01:00", "end_time" => "16:00");
$h4=array("day"=>"thu","start_time" => "", "end_time" => "");
$h5=array("day"=>"fri","start_time" => "01:00", "end_time" => "16:00");
$h6=array("day"=>"sat","start_time" => "01:00", "end_time" => "16:00");
$h7=array("day"=>"sun","start_time" => "01:00", "end_time" => "16:00");
$list=array();


array_push($list,$h);
array_push($list,$h2);
array_push($list,$h3);
array_push($list,$h4);
array_push($list,$h5);
array_push($list,$h6);
array_push($list,$h7);
```

**Outputs**

mon 01:01 to 16:00

tue-wed 01:00 to 16:00

thu Off Day

fri-sun 01:00 to 16:00

Comment: I used that $list for my tests though. Does this answer works for you , mark it as correct if so.  It would be interesting if you gave me your original php array not the var_dump version, or a JSON version would be good.

Comment: I detected an issue, when the last day of the week ( sunday ) has  a different time from the "saturday", so it will not be included. but i will then correct my answer!

Comment: thanks for your help.but i done with mysql query. that was easy and more accurate.